# How to structure multiple inputs with labels and fieldsets within a form

Tags: html, forms, dom, fieldset

What is the "most" **valid way to structure a form element** which contains several logically divided fieldsets with mutiple inputs?

After some research I found out that this *might* be the answer but I am not sure about it:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label></label>
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label></label>
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label></label>
            <input>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label></label>
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label></label>
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label></label>
            <input>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is the `p` tag a valid way to wrap those `input` and `label` pairs within a `fieldset`?

Answer (score 0):

The `p` tag is not a valid way to divide those inputs, the valid way is to use a linebreak `<br/>`.

You could structure the fieldsets better if you'd add a legend to these *(ofcourse this debatable because this is mainly personal preference)*.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal details</legend>
            <label>First name:</label><input/><br/>
            <label>Last name:</label><input/><br/>
            <label>Age:</label><input/><br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Other details</legend>
            <label>Address:</label><input/><br/>
            <label>E-mail Address:</label><input/><br/>
            <label>Language:</label><input/><br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
legend {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

fieldset {
    position:relative;
    line-height:24px;
}

input {
    position:absolute;
    left:115px;
}
```

[**`JSFiddle Demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/G62XA/2/)

Comment: So how would you then structure your form if you want to use more `label` `input` pairs inline?

Comment: You're able to do this with `position:absolute;`, normally you would do it with `<tr>` and `<td>` but because this is not directly in the form itself it seems to be impossible. http://jsfiddle.net/G62XA/2/

Comment: Please have look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html W3C also structures its forms in examples with the help of the `p` tag if I get it right.

Comment: It's not that they structure it with the `<p>` tag, it's more that they just add an entire paragraph where they also add text-area's and inputs in. This way they don't have to add multiple paragraph tags.